# In a SELECT how can I change what shows when I select a BIT column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column like this:

```
 [p3] BIT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
```

In a select statement I want to return "p3" if this is set to 1 and "" if it is set to 0.

Is there an easy way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Choose` or `IIF` function

```
Select Choose([p3]+1 , '' ,'p3')
From yourtable

Select IIF([p3]=0 , '' ,'p3')
From yourtable
```

for older versions use `CASE` statement

```
Select Case when [p3] = 0 then '' else 'p3' End
From yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
case when p3 = 1 then 'p3' else '' end 
from yourTable
```